# Calibration of Antennae in satellite and in ground station

Tags: artificial-satellite, antenna, telemetry

How to orient the ground station antenna and that of the satellite just after the launch?

Comment: Just after the launch the satellite antenna dish is covered by the fairing and could not be oriented to the ground station. But in this phase of flight, the telemetry data from the rocket is more important than data from the satellite. Transmission to the satellite and back is necessary when placed into orbit and separated from the last stage of the rocket.

Comment: @Uwe it's possible the OP does mean the rocket's antenna for telemetry, rather than the payload's antenna. Let's see if Nithin clarifies.

Comment: @Nithinrahav do you mean the antenna of the rocket's payload (satellite) while it is still inside the fairing, or do you mean the antenna for the rocket while it is still in the process of launching to orbit?

Comment: It's about antenna in telemetry.